# curl_exec issue in Magento 2.4.1 and PHP 7.4.x

Tags: magento2.4.1, curl

I have following code in the Magento site for getting external site data in PHP file, this worked fine in Magento CE 2.3.6 site but getting HTTP error code 400(Bad Request) after upgrading Magento to CE ver. 2.4.1-p1. I came across cURL way of making calls in Magento 2 but couldn't find any documentation on why current code wouldn't work.

Any ideas on what the issue is here?

```
const EXT_URL = "http://www.myexturl.com/blah/";
$ch = curl_init();
$myurl = self::EXT_URL . $param1 . "/" . $param2;
print_r($myurl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$s_output = curl_exec($ch);
// Getting 400 error code -- Bad Request. Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
print_r($s_output);
```

Note that the external URL call with hard coded parameters work fine from the browser and using curl command inside the Magento server, so it's not a firewall or network issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at Magento [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/gs-curl.html) examples I changed above code to use `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` and it's now working fine. I guess it appears that Magento 2.4.x does not support curl_exec PHP approach.

```
// post method
$this->curl->post($myurl, []);
$this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$s_output = $this->curl->getBody();
// for debugging only
print_r($s_output);

$my_data = json_decode($s_output);
```